# remove last slash or forward slash in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

other domain

```
http://domain.com/name/directory/brand/ <<< this last slash
http://domain.com/name/directory/check/me/ <<< this last slash
```

main page

```
http://doamin.com/name/directory/index.php
```

my intention is whatever url the person enter , it will always redirect to them to the main page and i also want to remove the last slash or forward slash at the last of the url , not matter what url they enter , i dont want to contain last slash.

i did get the them to redirect to main , but i cant get the url remove.

this is my code

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /name/directory/index.php [QSA,L]
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if not a directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]

# rewrite everything to index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ name/directory/index.php [L]
```

Comment: thank you , but when i refresh it be like this http://doamin.com/directory

Comment: any idea how to not remove the /name/

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. Can you clarify what is the problem with these rules and what you mean by `not remove the /name/`